# Why image's source does not change? How does scrset work?

Tags: html

I'm using scrset attribute for img tag and it seems not changing src at all. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
 <img 
    src="download.jpg"
    srcset="download.jpg 350w, mushroom_landscape.jpg 550w, t_1_lisitsa.jpg 880w" 
    sizes="(min-width: 880px) 300px, (min-width: 600px) 600px, 500px"
    alt="">
```

The size of image is changing but the actual image does not

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 880px)" srcset="download.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="mushroom_landscape.jpg">
  <img src="download.jpg" alt="" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Comment: I know about this tag, but I wanted to find out how to make my example work

Comment: @ТаняБіланюк you should change your browser size to see the change of image.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, I asked this question because when I change window's width source of image remains the same.